# USB mouse/keyboard not working in Windows 7 Setup DVD?

Tags: windows-7, setup, efi, windows-installation

I've just updated my ASUS Sabertooth P67 BIOS from version 1305 to 1850 and I'm trying to reinstall Windows 7 (x64) but when I boot to the DVD, my USB keyboard and mouse don't work.

They work fine in the UEFI BIOS and fine in my current installation of Windows 7, but in the Windows Setup menu, they don't work.

Also, they seemed to work fine with BIOS 1305.

Does anybody else have this problem and know how to solve it? :(

Comment: You may need to plug them in (again) after the setup environment has loaded to trigger device discovery. Otherwise see if there's any option in your BIOS about USB keyboard/mouse emulation and toggle it and see what happens. \